# C/C++ Makefile -- is it possible to auto detect header dependency?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Here is my general makefile for C/C++ programming, which is good in:

- Source, objects and binary are under separated directories;
- Auto detect source (*c, *.cpp, etc.) files. No need to modify makefile when new source files are added;
- Mixed C and C++ is supported.

However, one big drawback is, it is based only on **source files,** not **header files**.  If a header file is modified, the makefile will not detect this change, and will not re-compile the source files that has dependency on it. I have to make clean and make again.

Is it possible to do some change on my makefile so that: when some header files are modified, source files that directly or indirectly include it will be re-compiled?

The majority is not my own. I just make minor modifications based on my favour.

```
#
# Generic Makefile for C/C++ Program
#
# License: GPL (General Public License)
# Author:  whyglinux <whyglinux AT gmail DOT com>
# Date:    2006/03/04 (version 0.1)
#          2007/03/24 (version 0.2)
#          2007/04/09 (version 0.3)
#          2007/06/26 (version 0.4)
#          2008/04/05 (version 0.5)
#
# Author: echyanq (chen9007@gmail.com)
# Date:    2016/09/27
# Modified based on one artical on chinaunix.com
# Allows to specify directories for obj, bin and dep
#
# Description:
# ------------
# This is an easily customizable makefile template. The purpose is to
# provide an instant building environment for C/C++ programs.
#
# It searches all the C/C++ source files in the specified directories,
# makes dependencies, compiles and links to form an executable.
#
# Besides its default ability to build C/C++ programs which use only
# standard C/C++ libraries, you can customize the Makefile to build
# those using other libraries. Once done, without any changes you can
# then build programs using the same or less libraries, even if source
# files are renamed, added or removed. Therefore, it is particularly
# convenient to use it to build codes for experimental or study use.
#
# GNU make is expected to use the Makefile. Other versions of makes
# may or may not work.
#
# Usage:
# ------
# 1. Copy the Makefile to your program directory.
# 2. Customize in the "Customizable Section" only if necessary:
#    * to use non-standard C/C++ libraries, set pre-processor or compiler
#      options to <MY_CFLAGS> and linker ones to <MY_LIBS>
#      (See Makefile.gtk+-2.0 for an example)
#    * to search sources in more directories, set to <SRCDIRS>
#    * to specify your favorite program name, set to <PROGRAM>
# 3. Type make to start building your program.
#
# Make Target:
# ------------
# The Makefile provides the following targets to make:
#   $ make           compile and link
#   $ make NODEP=yes compile and link without generating dependencies
#   $ make objs      compile only (no linking)
#   $ make tags      create tags for Emacs editor
#   $ make ctags     create ctags for VI editor
#   $ make clean     clean objects and the executable file
#   $ make distclean clean objects, the executable and dependencies
#   $ make help      get the usage of the makefile
#
#===========================================================================

## Customizable Section: adapt those variables to suit your program.
##==========================================================================

# The pre-processor and compiler options.
MY_CFLAGS = -Wno-unused-variable

# The linker options.
MY_LIBS   = 

# The pre-processor options used by the cpp (man cpp for more).
CPPFLAGS  = -Wall

# The options used in linking as well as in any direct use of ld.
LDFLAGS   =

# The directories in which source files reside.
# If not specified, only the current directory will be serached.
SRCDIRS   = src

# The executable file name.
# If not specified, current directory name or `a.out' will be used.
PROGRAM   =

BINDIRS   = bin
OBJDIRS   = obj
DEPDIRS   = dep

## Implicit Section: change the following only when necessary.
##==========================================================================

# The source file types (headers excluded).
# .c indicates C source files, and others C++ ones.
SRCEXTS = .c .C .cc .cpp .CPP .c++ .cxx .cp

# The header file types.
HDREXTS = .h .H .hh .hpp .HPP .h++ .hxx .hp

# The pre-processor and compiler options.
# Users can override those variables from the command line.
CFLAGS  = -g -O2
CXXFLAGS= -g -O2

# The C program compiler.
#CC     = gcc

# The C++ program compiler.
#CXX    = g++

# Un-comment the following line to compile C programs as C++ ones.
#CC     = $(CXX)

# The command used to delete file.
#RM     = rm -f

ETAGS = etags
ETAGSFLAGS =

CTAGS = ctags
CTAGSFLAGS =

## Stable Section: usually no need to be changed. But you can add more.
##==========================================================================
SHELL   = /bin/sh
EMPTY   =
SPACE   = $(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
ifeq ($(PROGRAM),)
  CUR_PATH_NAMES = $(subst /,$(SPACE),$(subst $(SPACE),_,$(CURDIR)))
  PROGRAM = $(word $(words $(CUR_PATH_NAMES)),$(CUR_PATH_NAMES))
  ifeq ($(PROGRAM),)
    PROGRAM = a.out
  endif
endif
ifeq ($(SRCDIRS),)
  SRCDIRS = .
endif
SOURCES = $(foreach d,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*,$(SRCEXTS))))
HEADERS = $(foreach d,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(d)/*,$(HDREXTS))))
SRC_CXX = $(filter-out %.c,$(SOURCES))
#OBJS    = $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SOURCES)))
OBJS    = $(addsuffix .o, $(addprefix $(OBJDIRS)/,$(notdir $(basename $(SOURCES)))))
#DEPS    = $(OBJS:.o=.d)
DEPS    = $(addsuffix .d, $(addprefix $(DEPDIRS)/,$(notdir $(basename $(SOURCES)))))

## Define some useful variables.
DEP_OPT = $(shell if `$(CC) --version | grep "GCC" >/dev/null`; then \
                  echo "-MM -MP"; else echo "-M"; fi )
DEPEND      = $(CC)  $(DEP_OPT)  $(MY_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
DEPEND.d    = $(subst -g ,,$(DEPEND))
COMPILE.c   = $(CC)  $(MY_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)   $(CPPFLAGS) -c
COMPILE.cxx = $(CXX) $(MY_CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c
LINK.c      = $(CC)  $(MY_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)   $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
LINK.cxx    = $(CXX) $(MY_CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: all objs tags ctags clean distclean help show

# Delete the default suffixes
.SUFFIXES:

all: $(BINDIRS)/$(PROGRAM)

# Rules for creating dependency files (.d).
#------------------------------------------
MKDEPDIR = mkdir -p $(DEPDIRS)
$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.c
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.C
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cc
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cpp
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.CPP
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.c++
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cp
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

$(DEPDIRS)/%.d:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cxx
    @$(MKDEPDIR)
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

# Rules for generating object files (.o).
#----------------------------------------
MKOBJDIR = mkdir -p $(OBJDIRS)
objs:$(OBJS)

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.c
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.C
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cc
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cpp
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.CPP
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.c++
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cp
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS)/%.o:$(SRCDIRS)/%.cxx
    @$(MKOBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cxx) $< -o $@

# Rules for generating the tags.
#-------------------------------------
tags: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)
    $(ETAGS) $(ETAGSFLAGS) $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)

ctags: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)
    $(CTAGS) $(CTAGSFLAGS) $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)

# Rules for generating the executable.
#-------------------------------------
MKBINDIR = mkdir -p $(BINDIRS)
$(BINDIRS)/$(PROGRAM):$(OBJS)
ifeq ($(SRC_CXX),)              # C program
    @$(MKBINDIR)
    $(LINK.c)  $(OBJS) $(MY_LIBS) -o $@
    @cp $(BINDIRS)/$(PROGRAM) ./
    @echo Type ./$@ to execute the program.
else                            # C++ program
    @$(MKBINDIR)
    $(LINK.cxx) $(OBJS) $(MY_LIBS) -o $@
    @cp $(BINDIRS)/$(PROGRAM) ./
    @echo Type ./$@ to execute the program.
endif

ifndef NODEP
ifneq ($(DEPS),)
  sinclude $(DEPS)
endif
endif

clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(OBJDIRS) $(BINDIRS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) -rf $(DEPDIRS) TAGS

# Show help.
help:
    @echo 'Generic Makefile for C/C++ Programs (gcmakefile) version 0.5'
    @echo 'Copyright (C) 2007, 2008 whyglinux <whyglinux@hotmail.com>'
    @echo
    @echo 'Usage: make [TARGET]'
    @echo 'TARGETS:'
    @echo '  all       (=make) compile and link.'
    @echo '  NODEP=yes make without generating dependencies.'
    @echo '  objs      compile only (no linking).'
    @echo '  tags      create tags for Emacs editor.'
    @echo '  ctags     create ctags for VI editor.'
    @echo '  clean     clean objects and the executable file.'
    @echo '  distclean clean objects, the executable and dependencies.'
    @echo '  show      show variables (for debug use only).'
    @echo '  help      print this message.'
    @echo
    @echo 'Report bugs to <whyglinux AT gmail DOT com>.'

# Show variables (for debug use only.)
show:
    @echo 'PROGRAM     :' $(PROGRAM)
    @echo 'BINDIRS     :' $(BINDIRS)
    @echo 'OBJDIRS     :' $(OBJDIRS)
    @echo 'DEPDIRS     :' $(DEPDIRS)
    @echo 'SRCDIRS     :' $(SRCDIRS)
    @echo 'HEADERS     :' $(HEADERS)
    @echo 'SOURCES     :' $(SOURCES)
    @echo 'SRC_CXX     :' $(SRC_CXX)
    @echo 'OBJS        :' $(OBJS)
    @echo 'DEPS        :' $(DEPS)
    @echo 'DEPEND      :' $(DEPEND)
    @echo 'COMPILE.c   :' $(COMPILE.c)
    @echo 'COMPILE.cxx :' $(COMPILE.cxx)
    @echo 'link.c      :' $(LINK.c)
    @echo 'link.cxx    :' $(LINK.cxx)

## End of the Makefile ##  Suggestions are welcome  ## All rights reserved ##
#############################################################################
```

Comment: There's a ton of information about this online - like http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html . Do a little searching/reading.

Comment: Dupehammer-wielder needs to pay more attention, preferably actually reading the question before closing it. The code already contains facilities to use "depends" and ".d" files, so pointing to a question suggesting their use is not helpful.

Comment: Where is the command that builds the dependencies?